# Tidyverse -- integrating mutate select and case when to likert scales

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I'm a *tidyverse* user and I'm facing a difficulty to perform what I imagine is a simple command.

I have a dataset where some variables are Likert scales and, now, I want to assign some text labels to these specific set of variables. To do that, I imagine the best process involves to **mutate**, then **select** which variables I want to change and, then, **tell R what will be the new values**.

That seems logic to me. However, there is a bridge between what I want to do and the R code I'm creating.

I hope someone can help me to resolve this question.

The code below is a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
ds <- data.frame(sex=c(0,1), age=rnorm(n = 100, mean = 7, sd=2),
                 question1_1 = sample(1:5),
                 question1_2 = sample(1:5),
                 question1_3 = sample(1:5),
                 question1_4 = sample(1:5),
                 question1_5 = sample(1:5))
ds <- ds %>% mutate(
  select %>% starts_with("question1_") %>% 
  case_when(. == 1 ~ "Strongly disagree",
            . == 2 ~ "Disagree",
            . == 3 ~ "Neutral",
            . == 4 ~ "Agree",
            . == 5 ~ "Strongly agree"))
```

I did not find any previous message asking the same question and because of that, I create this new thread. Please let me know if this message is duplicate to exclude it.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use it in `mutate_at`

```
ds %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with('question')), 
         funs(case_when(.==1 ~ "Strongly disagree",
                        .==2 ~ "Disagree",
                        .==3 ~ "Neutral",
                        .==4 ~ "Agree",
                        .==5 ~ "Strongly agree")))
```

---

But, this can be made more simpler as the values are integers, so pass a `vector` of strings in the same order we want to change making use of the integer values as indexes

```
v1 <- c('Strongly disagree', 'Disagree', 'Neutral', 'Agree', 'Strongly agree')
ds %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with('question')),
         funs(v1[.]))
```

Comment: You again helping me! I feel embarrassed to say I was trying to figure out this answer myself about 1 week before asking here. Thanks much!

Comment: @Luis It takes some time to get in grips with a new language.  Don't feel embarrased.  Keep on practising.  It will become simple for you within no time

Comment: A base `R` translation for those who will care: `cols_lgl <- startsWith(names(ds),"question"); ds[cols_lgl] <- lapply(ds[cols_lgl], function(x) c("Strongly disagree","Disagree","Neutral","Agree", "Strongly agree")[x])
`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use factors:

```
library(tidyverse)
ds %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('question')), factor, 
                 labels= c("Strongly disagree","Disagree","Neutral","Agree", "Strongly agree")) %>%
  head

#   sex      age       question1_1       question1_2       question1_3       question1_4       question1_5
# 1   0 6.518414             Agree           Neutral          Disagree           Neutral             Agree
# 2   1 4.972210           Neutral          Disagree    Strongly agree Strongly disagree Strongly disagree
# 3   0 6.422792 Strongly disagree    Strongly agree             Agree          Disagree    Strongly agree
# 4   1 9.839967          Disagree             Agree           Neutral    Strongly agree           Neutral
# 5   0 7.518809    Strongly agree Strongly disagree Strongly disagree             Agree          Disagree
# 6   1 8.446730             Agree           Neutral          Disagree           Neutral             Agree
```

Translated in base `R`:

```
cols_lgl <- startsWith(names(ds),"question")
ds[cols_lgl] <- lapply(ds[cols_lgl],factor, labels= c("Strongly disagree","Disagree","Neutral","Agree", "Strongly agree"))
```